# How to use 'CSSTransition' in react-router that has 'Link' in each component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, css-transitions

I have a 'CSSTransition' component encompassing the 'Routes', but I can't put a function that changes the 'state' in the 'Link' components, because each one is in different files

In routes.js

```
const Routes = () =\> {

    const [isEnter, setIsEnter] = useState(false)
    
    return(
        <CSSTransition
            in={isEnter}
            timeout={4000}
            classNames='fade'
        >
            <Router>
                <Routes>
                    <Route exact path='/' element={<StartPage />} />
                    <Route path='/question-one' element={<FirstQuestion />} />
                    <Route path='/question-two' element={<FavoritePerson />} />
                    <Route path='/question-three' element={<ChoseMode />} />
                    <Route path='/first-message' element={<SuccessPage />} />
                    <Route path='/question-four' element={<FavoriteDate />} />
                    <Route path='/last-question' element={<DoYouWannaDateMe />} />
                </Routes>
            </Router>
        </CSSTransition>
    )

}

export default Routes;
```

In each component

```
export default function StartPage() {

return (
\<div className="card"\>

        <h1 className='card-title'>Está pronta?</h1>
        <form>
          <Link to='/question-one' className='button-submit'
          onClick={()=>{
            setIsEnter()
          }}
          >SIM</Link>
          <input type='button' value='NÂO' onClick={warningMessage}></input>
        </form>
        
      </div>

);

}
```

The function 'setIsEnter()', that change the state of 'CSStransition' is not defined in StartPage.js

Comment: Where is, or should, the `setIsEnter` function be declared?

Comment: This video taught me perfectly what I wanted, a component <TransitionGroup> parent of <CSS Transition> solved it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMLqvaq5r4Y

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, i have this option.
Declare component, that you need, and pass it for all routes as a props.

```
function func() {...}

<Route path='/question-one' element={<FirstQuestion func={func} />}
```